# Why is Qe7 a blunder here?

Tags: analysis, learning, beginner

I'm a chess beginner. I played this game against Stockfish and according to Lichess' analysis, Qe7 was a blunder here, and the best move actually was c6. I can't understand why?

```
[Title "Why is Qe7 a blunder?"]
[fen "r1bqkb1r/pppp1ppp/5n2/8/2Q1P3/2N2N2/PPP2PPP/R1B1K2R b KQkq - 0 1"]

1... Qe7? (1...c6)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qe7 is a blunder for a number of reasons:

1. It blocks your f8 bishop
2. When you are already behind in development and having given up the center it does nothing for your development and does not fight for control of the center
3. It gives away the c7 pawn
4. It does not threaten to win the e4 pawn. If you do try and take it it will be very bad for you with your king and queen lined up on an open file and white's rook coming quickly to e1.

Here is what could happen:

```
[Title "Qe7"]
[fen "r1bqkb1r/pppp1ppp/5n2/8/2Q1P3/2N2N2/PPP2PPP/R1B1K2R b KQkq - 0 1"]

1... Qe7 2. Qxc7 Nxe4 3. O-O Nxc3 4. Qxc3 d5 5. Re1 Be6 6. Bf4 Rc8 (6...Qc5 7. Qe5) 7. Qd2
```

In both cases white has castled and completed development apart from the a1 rook. Meanwhile black's king is stuck in the center with an open center.

c7, on the other hand, protects the c pawn, stops the white knight from coming to b5 and lays the groundwork some time in the future for a possible d5 to contest the center.

Yes, after c7 the pawn push e5 looks scary but fortunately there is d5 for black and after white moves the queen there is a safe square for the f6 knight on d7.

```
[Title "c7"]
[fen "r1bqkb1r/pppp1ppp/5n2/8/2Q1P3/2N2N2/PPP2PPP/R1B1K2R b KQkq - 0 1"]

1... c6 2. e5? (2. Bg5 d6 3. O-O-O Be6) d5!
```

And white is better but black is still in the game.

Answer (score 0):

Qe7 is a blunder because after Bg5! Black is lost.Stockfish played Bg5 right?